# If a molecule is a collection of atoms why we can't call a molecule matter and vice versa?

Tags: terminology, definition, atoms, molecules, matter

if a molecule is a collection of atoms why we cant call a molecule matter and matter a molecule?

what is the difference between the two?

in school we are taught that matter is made up of molecules and molecules are made up of atoms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A molecule is a state of matter, just like atoms.
So molecules are matter.
The opposite is not always true since a molecule is a type of organization of matter, binding multiple atoms together.
So single atoms or even a single particle like an electron are matter, but they are not molecules.

Answer (score 1):

Matter is a generic term and before matter was discovered to be made up of atoms, around the turn of the 20th C, and hence molecules it was thought of as a kind of plenum, that is infinitely divisible like a continua.

To call molecules matter is really to mix up terms here. We really ought to say, as I've already said, matter is made up of molecules and atoms (and ions).

Answer (score 1):

This is really a question about how the English language works - which is certainly not always consistent or logical.

A herd of horses is made up of horses and a horse is made up of cells. Is a cell a horse ? Is a horse a herd ?